# How to remove the APE tag in an MP3 file?

Tags: audio, mp3, tagging

An MP3 file can support three different types of tags (that I am aware of): ID3V1, ID3V2.4 and APE. I would like to know how to remove an APE tag in an MP3 file or files, since it is giving me headaches with my audio player. I am familiar with EasyTag and, more recently (today), with Mp3Diags; however, none of them seems to be able to just delete the APE tag.

Answer (score 2):

Install the good old [apetag](http://www.muth.org/Robert/Apetag/) ([github](https://github.com/robertmuth/apetag)), then do something like this:

```
find /some/dir -iname '*.mp3' -exec apetag -i {} -m overwrite \;
```

It's probably a good idea to make backups, and try the operation on a small subset of files first.

Comment: Use the version at GitHub instead. The old version (1.12) seems unable to read an APE tag from a MP3 file with an ID3 v1 tag.

Answer (score 1):

To purge only the APE tag from an MP3 file, use the `erase` mode from newer versions of `apetag` available at [GitHub](https://github.com/robertmuth/apetag)

```
apetag -m erase -i file.mp3
```

(This preserves the ID3 v1 tag if any.)

Comment: This preserves (IDE v1 & ID3v2.3) tags and just removes junk APE tags. For glob use `for f in *.mp3; do apetag -m erase -i "$f"; done`

Comment: Unfortunately does not work if there is a Lyrics3 tag.